# EXT Js: Calling a method of a ViewController from another ViewController

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, extjs6-classic

I am very new EXTJs and trying to call a method of a viewController from another ViewController. Below is my ViewController which has a showData function. I have another view controller below and that has a method inside it which i wanted to call from my first viewcontroller inside showdata function.

```
    Ext.define('myapp.view.main.ViewportController', {
        extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',
        alias: 'controller.mainviewport',

        showData : function(id) {
            var me = this;
            //Call the showUserData method here
        }


Ext.define('myapp.view.user.UserController',
    {
        extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',
        requires: [
            'Ext.window.MessageBox'
        ],
        alias: 'controller.usercontroller',
       showUserData : function(id) {

         }
```

Comment: you can use events to communicate between Controllers

Comment: With Ext.define you create a class and every class can be instantiated by  Ext.create that returns a reference of the instance, after that you can call the method. If the class has created before you should obtain its reference.

Comment: chck this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32934591/accessing-functions-in-viewcontroller-from-form-created-on-the-fly/32937013#32937013